# Https Android Clent to Server Connection without Client Certificate using keypair(public/private) instead

Tags: android, https, certificate

I have tried to implement a method to get `HttpsConnection`. Server
replies the data. but client cannot read it. So please, guide me to create
proper connection to Https server without Client Certificate but use keypair instead.

Please refer code.

```
public HttpsURLConnection getSslConnection(String uri, String authCode){

    int status=0;
    try{
         //uri="https://www.google.lk";
        // uri="https://192.168.8.146:8081/Login";

        Log.i("prageeth","test1");

        //Retrive Server Certificate
        URL url=new URL(uri);
        SSLContext sslContext=SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

        sslContext.init(null,new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager(){
            X509Certificate[] accepted=null;
            @Override

            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {

            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                accepted=chain;
            }

            @Override
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return accepted;
            }
        }},new SecureRandom());

        urlConnection=(HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();

        setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                  return true;
             }
         });
        urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());

        String keyStoreType="AES";
        KeyPairGenerator kg=KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");

        KeyPair kp=kg.generateKeyPair();
        KeyStore ks=KeyStore.getInstance("AES");
        ks.load(null);
        KeyStore.Entry entry=KeyStore.getInstance(alias,null);

        Log.i("test",kp.getPublic().toString());
        Log.i("test",kp.getPrivate().toString());

        ??????


        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Authorization","Basic " + authCode);
        Log.i("prageeth","test5");
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);

        InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        //Log.i("test",in.toString());
        Log.i("test","test55");
        try {
            urlConnection.connect();
        }catch (Exception a){
            Log.i("test",a.getMessage());
        }
        String status1;
        status1=urlConnection.getResponseMessage();
        Log.i("test", status1);
        InputStream dataInputStream=urlConnection.getInputStream();

       // Log.i("test", dataInputStream.toString());

    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.i("test",e.getMessage().toString());
    }
     try {
         int status2 = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
         Log.i("test","test6");
     }catch (Exception ex){
         Log.i("test",  ex.getMessage().toString());
     }
    return  urlConnection;
}
```